# Laravel validate field with external SOAP request

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I have created a function soapRequest() in my AuthController.php using .wsdl file from a website to check if VAT number exists:

```
public function soapRequest(Request $request) {

    $countryCode = $request->countryCode;
    $vatNo = $request->vat_number;

    $client = new \SoapClient("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl");

    $result = $client->checkVat(['countryCode' => $countryCode, 'vatNumber' => $vatNo]);

    $result = ($result->valid == true) ? "VAT number OK" : "VAT number INVALID";


    return response()->json(['msg' => $result], 200);

}
```

and in my view i just write the number and i can see if the number is valid or not:

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        {!! Form::select('countryCode', [
                            ''  => '--Land auswählen',
                            'AT' => 'AT-Austria',
                            'BE' => 'BE-Belgium',
                            'BG' => 'BG-Bulgaria',
                            'CY' => 'CY-Cyprus',
                            'CZ' => 'CZ-Czech Republic',
                            'DE' => 'DE-Germany',
                            'DK' => 'DK-Denmark',
                            'EE' => 'EE-Estonia',
                            'EL' => 'EL-Greece',
                            'ES' => 'ES-Spain',
                            'FI' => 'FI-Finland',
                            'FR' => 'FR-France',
                            'GB' => 'GB-United Kingdom',
                            'HR' => 'HR-Croatia',
                            'HU' => 'HU-Hungary',
                            'IE' => 'IE-Ireland',
                            'IT' => 'IT-Italy',
                            'LT' => 'LT-Lithuania',
                            'LU' => 'LU-Luxembourg',
                            'LV' => 'LV-Latvia',
                            'MT' => 'MT-Malta',
                            'NL' => 'NL-The Netherlands',
                            'PL' => 'PL-Poland',
                            'PT' => 'PT-Portugal',
                            'RO' => 'RO-Romania',
                            'SE' => 'SE-Sweden',
                            'SI' => 'SI-Slovenia',
                            'SK' => 'SK-Slovakia'], 
                            null, ['id' => 'countryCode', 'class' => 'form-control']
                        ) !!}
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
        {!! Form::text('code', null, ['id' => 'code', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
        {!! Form::text('vat_number', null, ['id' => 'vat', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
        {!! Form::text('msg', null, ['id' => 'msg', 'disabled' => 'disabled', 'class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on('change', '#countryCode', function () {
        $('input[id=code]').val($('#countryCode').val());
    });

    $(document).on('input paste', '#vat, #countryCode', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/soap',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
            data: $('#countryCode, #vat').serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    $('input[id=msg]').val(data.msg);
                }
            });
    });

</script>
```

And actually i don't need it to work like this....i just need to verify/validate if user has inputted the existing number in that VAT Number input field.

So the question is:

How to validate that single input field in BACKEND so the user cannot input a non existing VAT number?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with cannot be manipulated? When a user submits a form you send the data from your browser to your server, and process everything. You should check if its an existing VAT with your soapRequest when you process the user input on your server.

Comment: Yes you are right....but at the moment i don't have validation for that field....how to verify it so that when user submits the form....it must be a valid VAT number

Comment: You should check it on the server, with your SOAP Request. Or (better idea) check it with Javascript after the user enters his VAT into the field and give him a short message (like make it green or something) if the validation has succeeded. The SoapRequest is server-side, whats the problem to check it AFTER the user sends the data with your form?

Comment: You mean when you save your data on your server?

Comment: the problem is that user actually gets this that message if number is Valid or not BUT it's just an information for the user....but he can still write any number that doesn't exist....and i want to make it so that the user cannot input an non existing VAT number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124534/discussion-between-derdida-and-lewis4u).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have your base Validation with Laravel, and now you can extend the validation by your SOAP Request: Like this:

```
$validation = [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|confirmed|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',     
    ...

$YourFormValidation = Validator::make($data,$validation);

if( $YourFormValidation->passes() ) { 
  // so all your data seems valid, check out VAT

  $countryCode = $request->countryCode;
  $vatNo = $request->vat_number;

  $client = new \SoapClient("http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl");

  $result = $client->checkVat(['countryCode' => $countryCode, 'vatNumber' => $vatNo]);

  if($result->valid == true) {
     // everyhting is correct, save data to database (or whatever)
  } else {
     // VAT seemed correct, but Webservice returns false. Show user an Information that the VAT is not correct.
  }

} else { 
    //code for validation failure
}
```